# how to get page url path from user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my user control i have HyperLink 
the link need to be to page named "export.ashx" in the same folder of the page that cotaines the user contrl

```
<asp:HyperLink CssClass="btnblue" ID="hypAddItem" Visible="false" NavigateUrl="" runat="server"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Part</asp:HyperLink>
```

and in my Code

```
hypAddItem.NavigateUrl = pageUrl + "Export.ashx";
```

what i need to put in the pageUrl that will work on each folder?

My directory structure

```
root
  folder1
    pageWithUC.aspx
    export.ashx
  folder2
     pagewithUC.aspx
     export.ashx
  usercontrols
    uc.acsx
```

Comment: ~/export.aspx... "~" stands for home directory.

Comment: my export.ashx is not in the home directory. he is in the page directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var url = Request.Url.FilePath;
var folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(url)
hypAddItem.NavigateUrl = folder + "/Export.ashx";
```

Comment: what is variable pageUrl ? I presume that this must be hypAddItem.NavigateUrl = folder + "/Export.ashx";

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
~/folder1/export.ashx
```

and if you want the second folder:

```
~/folder2/export.ashx
```

`~` sign stands for your root direcotry.

you can also go back one directory, from uc.acsx, and go inside folder1/folder2:

```
../folder1/export.ashx
```

Comment: the code is in the UC code not in the page. i dont want to add a property for the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current URL from request and combine it with your ashx, like this :

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, "Export.ashx");
```

then use Uri class methods to get relative path :

```
hypAddItem.NavigateUrl = myUri.PathAndQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Server.MapPath(~)  and use then folder along with it